# Do I need add ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0?

Tags: android

I have two BroadcastReceivers in my AndroidMainfest.xml, 
and set `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />` for bll.BootNotificationReceiver
`<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />` for bll.SmsBroadcastReceiver.

So I don't think I need add `ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0` in `public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)`, right?

AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<!-- Broadcast receiver -->
<receiver android:name="bll.SmsBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>              
       <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

SmsBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {      
            PublicPar.myContext=context;
        } 
    }   

}
```

BootNotificationReceiver.java

```
public class BootNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final String ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {
            PublicPar.SetNotification();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think I need add `ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0` in `public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)`, intresting....

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code is enough.

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
     @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {    
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {      
            PublicPar.myContext=context;
        } 
    }   

}


public class BootNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
      @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
            PublicPar.SetNotification();    
        }
    }

}
```